# Java FX performance issue

Tags: performance, javafx-2

We are having a complex Java FX application will lot of screens. As we navigate through the application at a point in time the application runs out of memory. Is there a way to remove the components created in a scene before we proceed to the next scene. 
Does the idea of removing the components from the scene which is no longer used, improve the performance ?

I see that there is no straight forward way of removing the elements in a scene ?

Can anyone please suggest a way to tune the slowness and out of memory issues in java fx applications ?

Answer (score 0):

You may try the [Pagination](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/pagination.htm) control. There is only one root at a time provided by the page factory.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i understand your question correctly, but i use a Screen Switch Controller in my Programm and with this Screen Switch I create each screen on the start of the programm once and then i use them and reload just the content each time.

https://blogs.oracle.com/acaicedo/entry/managing_multiple_screens_in_javafx1